# Accessing DOM objects with few identifiers (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm attempting to make my first ever chrome extension and I want to access the "Compose" button on Gmail via my content.js. I located the div that I want to use by inspecting the page, but I'm not sure how I can access it with Javascript since it's really deeply nested and doesn't have an ID attribute. I tried using document.querySelectorAll(".T-I.J-J5-Ji.T-I-KE.L3") and document.getElementsByClassName("T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3"), but the returned array was always empty. What am I doing wrong/what is a better way to access this element?

This is the HTML for the element I'm trying to get
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RLrm.png).

It would probably be easier to see the code I'm talking about by logging into Gmail (if you have one and right-clicking the "Compose" button and clicking Inspect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to type the command `document.getElementsByClassName("T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3")` in the console and it returned an array that contains theelement you are searching for.

I would say that your script do not have access to the entire document, so that you can not modify whatever you want, but I don't know enought about Chrome extension to be sure of that.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Try matching for `document.querySelector('[gh="cm"]');`.

I'm not sure what the `gh` attribute stands for, but its value `cm` represents the ComposeMessage button.